# bootstrap, input text with dropdown button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get this input text, with button dropdown to work. However there's no functionality when I click the button.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-dropdowns Following the "Buttons with dropdown"s

here's a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/jjpg9ofy/1/

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
         </div>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="...">
     </div>
```

my imports.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<!--  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
-->
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/lang/en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is missing jQuery, if you add it it works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/jjpg9ofy/2/

To add it to the fiddle:

```
expand Frameworks & Extensions in the top left corner
select a version of jQuery, e.g. 1.10.1.
```